# get the row with datetime which is the latest datetime less than a selected date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have to get the row with the latest date less than a given date selected from a select box.

I have figured out how to get the row with the latest date like

`select * from test_table where created in (select max(created) from test_table)`

I know I have to use a `created between` but I have not been able to solve it. The date which is the upper limit is selected from a select box. SO, I dont know it before hand.
Please help me

for example, let the date selected from textbox is Nov 11 2013. I have to get a row with a created date which is the max date in the table less than Nov 11 2013.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the rows that have the latest datetime less than @givendate:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test_table
WHERE  created = (SELECT max(created)
                  FROM test_table
                  WHERE created < @givendate)
```

please notice that there could be more than one row with the same latest datetime. Or you could simply use this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     test_table
WHERE    created < @givendate
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the second last entry use the offset of the `limit` function

```
select * 
from test_table 
order by created desc
limit 1,1
```

Comment: Technically, that's not quite the same thing. This assumes dates are unique. The OP's query (rightly or wrongly) implies otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * 
from test_table order by created desc
limit 1
```